# How to return objects or arrays from a chaining interface in PHP OOP?

Tags: php, fluent-interface, method-chaining, magic-methods, php-5.4

I am curious in writing a chaining interface in PHP OOP. I modified this sample code from the php.net website, and I want to take it further - how can I return objects or arrays from this kind of interface?

```
// Declare a simple class
class TestClass
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct($foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

$input = (object)array("title" => "page 1");
$class = new TestClass($input);
echo $class;
```

error,

> Catchable fatal error: Method TestClass::__toString() must return a
>   string value in C:\wamp\www\test\2013\php\fluent_interface.php on line
>   2

Should I use different magic method instead of `__toString` then?

**EDIT:**
Can I return this as my result,

```
stdClass Object ( [title] => page 1 )
```

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want you need to use following syntax:

```
print_r($class->foo);
```

The __toString() magic method tries to convert your whole class 'TestClass' to a string, but since the magic method is not returning a string, it is showing you that error. Of course you could also rewrite your __toString() method to do the following:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return print_r($this->foo, true);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: but it seems I can't access the properties inside the object, for instance, `$class = new TestClass($input);
echo $class->title;` I get this error `Notice: Undefined property: TestClass::$title in C:...fluent_interface.php on line 23` instead of `page 1`... how can I access the data inside the object then?

Comment: The foo property in your class contains another object that is your data. In your example you should use this syntax: $class->foo->title

Comment: got it by doing that myself before reading your answer. thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for either [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) functions:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return var_export($this->foo, true);
}
```

and var_export is better since it also return type of value (and, besides, in valid PHP-code format). Note, that `__toString()` method have nothing common with fluent interface. It's just different things.

Comment: thanks but how can I access the data inside the return object then? for instance, `echo $class->title;` I want to get `page 1` as the result. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. To replace your class instance by those, that was passed to constructor? If yes, why?

Comment: sorry, I got the answer by doing this `echo $class->foo->title;` thanks for the help.